# field with 'indexNullAs' not included in result set

Tags: java, spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to make use of `@IndexedEmbedded`'s `indexNullAs` property on a property which is null in the database:

```
...
@Indexed
public class DocVersion implements Serializable {
...
    @IndexedEmbedded(indexNullAs = "valid")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id")
    private ValidityRule validityRule;
...
}
```

in the db I have two records, one that have `validityRule` associated with the record and the other one that is null.

this is the part of the query I have constructed for hibernate search:

```
FullTextQueryImpl(-(+document2.docType.documentType:FOLDER) +(+document2.eDocState:ACTIVE) +(document2.docType.documentType:ACCOUNTSTATEMENT) +(+validityRule.validFrom:[* TO 0000020190601] +validityRule.validTo:[0000020190701 TO *] validityRule:valid))
```

this returns just one record, the one that is associated with the `validityRule` and conforms to the Date criteria.

My problem is that it won't return the second row that doesn't have set a validityRule.
I understand this `indexNullAs` as it should become 'valid' string when db field is not set. and  you can see it in the query?

So why I don't get the second row in the result set? what am I doing wrong?
I have deleted all the indexes from the dist and program is reindexing records on every run.

hibernate-search-orm: 5.10.4.Final

Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the query:

```
+validityRule.validFrom:[* TO 0000020190601] +validityRule.validTo:[0000020190701 TO *] validityRule:valid
```

What you are saying here is:

- `validityRule.validFrom` MUST be below 0000020190601
- `validityRule.validTo` MUST be above 0000020190701
- optionally, `validityRule` SHOULD be equal to `valid`, and in this case the score of the document should be slightly higher.

This roughly translates to the following boolean expression:

```
(
    validityRule.validFrom:[* TO 0000020190601]
    AND validityRule.validTo:[0000020190701 TO *]
)
```

The "SHOULD" clause doesn't appear in it, because it is optional. It does not affect matching, only the score.

What's important here is that "MUST"/"SHOULD" are not directly equivalent to the boolean operators "AND"/OR": they have their own meaning.
As a rule of thumb, if you want to implement "AND"/"OR" in a full-text query:

- For "AND", use a boolean query with only "MUST" clauses.
- For "OR", use a boolean query with only "SHOULD" clauses.
- Nest boolean queries as necessary to combine "AND" and "OR". Think of the boolean query as the parentheses in a traditional boolean expression: they prevent "AND" operators to mess with "OR" operators.
- Never mix "MUST" and "SHOULD" in the same boolean query unless you know what you are doing.

In your case, you will need two levels of boolean queries:

```
( // parent boolean query implementing "OR"
  ( // First "SHOULD" clause: a boolean query implementing "AND"
    +validityRule.validFrom:[* TO 0000020190601] // "MUST" clause
    +validityRule.validTo:[0000020190701 TO *] // "MUST" clause
  )
  validityRule:valid // Second "SHOULD" clause
)
```